# How can I find missing glPopMatrix() in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, opengl

I have a theory according to which the bugs I'm experiencing are due to a glPushMatrix() beign used without a matching glPopMatrix(). My project is rather big so I would like to be able to find these missing glPopMatrix() easily. I thought of using a search using regular expression, but I can't seem to find out how to find what I want (plus, regexp in visual studio isn't exactly the same as what I'm used to (php) so I'm a bit lost. Anyways, any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify your theory by checking if `glGetError()` returns `GL_STACK_OVERFLOW` at some point.

To find the missing references, I cannot think of anything better than to run a *full-text search on your project* for `glPushMatrix` and try to find the corresponding `glPopMatrix` for every one of them.

Or there's one more solution:

You can use an OpenGL debugger like [GLIntercept](http://glintercept.nutty.org/) (which comes in the form of an altered `opengl32.dll` file and dumps a lot of useful information, including all the OpenGL commands which were executed (there can be a flat log or a single-frame log of them). This can give you a good view on what went wrong and when.

Comment: Shouldn't you look out for `GL_STACK_OVERFLOW` if you have an extra `glPushMatrix()`?